# PDFlib use transparent colors

Tags: php, pdf, pdflib

I have a table and I want to give it a background color with light transparency. I know we have the option "fillcolor" but there we can only use something like rgb (means no use of rgba) and color codes which looks like this: `fillcolor={rgba 0.9 0.5 0}` or `fillcolor={#ffed00}`.

So how can I make the background more transparent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this in PDFlib if you create a **GState** with "*opacityfill*" and then output that when placing the table. In a simple code example this looks like this:

```php
        $gstate= $p->create_gstate("opacityfill=.5");
        $tbl = $p->add_table_cell($tbl, 1, 1,
              "Text", 
              "fittextline={fontname=NotoSerif-Regular encoding=unicode " + 
              "fontsize=12} colwidth=100 rowheight=30");

        $result = $p->fit_table($tbl, 50, 50, 500, 800, "fill={ {area=table fillcolor={red} } } gstate=" . $gstate);
```

This code fragment then leads to the following output if you then place the table on a colored background (such as an image), for example:
[image: screenshot of PDF output in Acrobat]

Please also refer to chapter 7.2 "Graphics State" in the PDFlib API Reference for full details on create_gstate().
Maybe also interesting, if you want to have the effect only on one cell, you can also define the decoration of a cell using Matchbox and you can specify a GState with it. (see PDFlib 9.3.1 Tutorial, chapter 9.4 "Matchboxes" for further details)

Comment: thank you so much for your explanation, this helped me a lot! Also do you maybe know if it's possible to create a table border only for the bottom of specific rows? I know we have the option to set a table border for the whole table with the option `stroke{={line=other}}`  for fit_table, but I don't want a border for the whole table.

Comment: please see answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68997642/2862406